# Using the tools in JDK 7 on java process running using JRE 8 java

Tags: heap-dump, azul-zulu

There is a requirement to generate thread and heap dumps of running Java process on a Window server. We have JDK 7 on the server, but the Java process runs using java in JRE 8. Installing JDK 8 on the server takes time due to lots of paperwork required for it (company process). The team who will be doing it insists that they need JDK 8 from Azul to generate the dumps since current java process uses Zulu JRE 8. For reasons known only to them, they do not even want to try with the tools available with JDK 7 (OpenJDK?) installed on the server. Does these versions really matter?

Question: Can I use JDK tools from any version, specifically JDK 7, to generate heap and thread dumps of the java process running from a Zulu JRE 8 environment?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be yes.

I just tried this on my Mac and could generate a thread dump and heap dump using the Zulu 7 version of jstack and jmap on a running instance of Zulu 8.  This would indicate that jstack/jmap are not troubled by the version number of the JVM (and also seem compatible).

Certainly, from a licensing perspective, there is no issue with using tools from a Zulu 7 build on other versions of Zulu (like 8).

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this too. Using JDK7 tools, I was able to generate the heap dump of a java process running from JRE 8 java. Was able to load the dump in a Memory Analyzer fine. For some reason the R&D team is asking to generate the dump from JDK 8 itself :). May be they are asking for more time :)